# All tests are executed although no code changes

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, tfsbuild, devops

In vNext (TFS 2017.3 on prem) I have a build definition which builds a .NET application and run around 3000 tests.

In my Visual Studio Test task I have enabled "Run only impacted tests" to decrease build time. I have done several builds at the same branch (Git) where I know there are no code changes. So my expectation was that the first build would take more time that if the "Run only impacted test" wasn't enabled because it should do extended analysis.
But then in the next build I would assume that no tests were executed as the code haven't changed.

But what is actually happen is that only 14 tests are "Not impacted".

Do you know why?

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on Test Impact Analysis and determine if any of the scenarios where TIA falls back to running all of the tests apply to you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/test/test-impact-analysis

Comment: I believe so and as I wrote I haven't changed any code between the builds and it doesn't take all, as 14 of them are "Not impacted". Sorry I wrote ignored in my description. I have changed that.

Answer (score 0):

TIA is presently scoped to the following:

***Supported***

- TFS 2017 Update 1 onwards and on VSTS
- Version 2.* of the Visual Studio Test task in the build definition
- Build vNext, with multiple VSTest Tasks
- VS2015 Update 3 onwards on the build agent
- Local and hosted build agents
- CI and in PR workflows
- Git, GitHub, External Git, TFVC repos
- IIS interactions (over REST, SOAP APIs), using HTTP/HTTPS protocols
- Automated Tests
- Single box topology (tests and application must be running on the
  same machine)
- Managed code (any .NET Framework application, any .NET Service)

***Not yet supported***

- Multi box topology (where the test is exercising an app deployed to a
  different machine)
- Data driven tests
- Test Adapter-specific parallel test execution
- .NET Core
- UWP

Please check whether you have a supported scope. More details please refer to the blog below:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/02/accelerated-continuous-testing-with-test-impact-analysis-part-1/

Comment: I'm quite sure I do and there are also 14 test which is found "Not impacted". If my setup wasn't supported I assume 0 test would be found as "Not impacted":

Comment: Are all tests Automated Tests? Are you able to provide detailed steps to reproduce your scenario?